# Jquery-mobile's Multiselect control

Tags: jquery-mobile, multi-select

How can we achieve to select all options in a multiselect control of the jquery-mobile framework?

Answer (score 1):

Let us ask the question another way.  How can we best give users a way to select multiple related items in jquery mobile.  Select dropdowns present their own UX failings to begin with in that they require work on the part of the user to see what the options even are.  Mobile devices only compound the issue with their differing implementations of the control.

Instead, try this using grouped checkboxes.  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/

You will have more control over how the information is displayed and users will find it easier to see all the options at once.